# Entity Framework Code First Approach to Xamarin.Forms PCL app

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, portable-class-library

Can I have a **.NET Class Library project** with **Entity Framework 6.1.1** (in **windowsazure.mobileservices.backend.entity** nuget package) work with **Xamarin.Forms PCL** app? Is this achievable? If not what are the possible complications?

**Question Background:**
I am working on a **Xamarin.Forms** cross platform **PCL** app with **Azure Mobile Services back-end,** targeting **Android, iOS, Windows 8.1 and WinPhone 8.1**. I actually dont care about Windows 8.1 but Visual Studio does not allow me to remove this target. So it stays.

**Azure Mobile Services** is setup, but I need the tables to be generated automatically (strongly avoiding manually typing table definitions in azure portal). I decided to go EF code first way with **windowsazure.mobileservices.backend.entity** nuget package to achieve this. However, the **Xamarin.Forms** PCL project does not support additional assemblies.
I am thinking of adding this package into a separate class library project and referring to it from the PCL project.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "the Xamarin.Forms PCL project does not support additional assemblies"? I've never had a problem adding another nuget to a PCL. Or does that nuget not support the profile you are targeting?

Comment: that nuget not support the profile the PCL project targetrs Android, IOS, win phone 8.1 , win 8.1 @valdetero

Answer (score 1):

The `EntityData` type is the required superclass of DTOs on the server SDK. Unfortunately, it has dependencies that are not supported in a PCL project, so it has to be used with a full .NET 4.5 project.

You could instead use partial classes to share DTOs between client and server. Just put all of the non system property types in a common code file that's shared between client and server. Then, on the client, add the system property implementation (ID field, UpdatedAt optionally, Version optionally). On the server, add another partial class definition that inherits from `EntityData`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @lindydonna - msft. Do you have any example I can look at?

Comment: I don't have a sample, but I added more details to my answer.